# How to map 2 domain objects in one JPA repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 domain objects **Job** and **JobModified**. I want to map to a single Jpa repository, so that in the output I get correct mapping of field and value.
*Right now when I am only getting the **value** when I hit JobModified, but when I hit Job I am getting correct field -value mapping. Is there any way to do it without creating another repository
--------*

```
public interface IJobRepository extends JpaRepository<Job, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT DISTINCT " + " WJOB.JOB_SEQ_ID, " + " COMP.CMPNT_SEQ_ID, "
            + " WJOB.SHP_SEQ_ID, " + " WJOB.JOB_NUM," + " WJOB.JOB_DESC, " + " RPT.RPT_STTS, " + " DTLS.CUST_NM, "
            + " DTLS.RCPT_DT, " + " DTLS.SHPMNT_DT," + " DTLS.TRBN_SRL_NUM, ....... WJOB.JOB_SEQ_ID = CS.JOB_SEQ_ID")
    List<Job> requestJobs();

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT WJOB.JOB_SEQ_ID , " + " COMP.CMPNT_SEQ_ID , " + " WJOB.SHP_SEQ_ID , "
            + " WJOB.JOB_NUM , " + " WJOB.JOB_DESC , " + " RPT.RPT_STTS, " + ..................
            + " and DTLS.lst_updt_dt = trunc(sysdate -1) ")
    List<JobModified> fetchpreviousDayModifiedJobs();

}
```

----output when I hit JobModified------

```
[
  [
    214596,
    15,
    2,
    "0222",
    null,
    "WIP",
    "BRITISH COLUMBIA HYDRO",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    1475179622000,
    "501344153",
    1475179622000,
    "501344153",
    "N"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Can you add the class and field declarations for the two classes at the top? It is difficult to understand what you are asking for without looking at the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there isn't a way to have two entities share a single DAO repository as they are typed to a single Class, with the second being the ID type. Also, what is the relationship between the **Job** and **JobModified**? If it's just to show that the job has been updated, what about having an updated timestamp? Or having an ENUM show some sort of lifecycle state.

Also what you're attempting to do breaks a principle of OOP which would be single responsibility. Where a class knows how to do one thing and do it well.

Comment: Yeah..I think you are correct , it is breaking the OOP concept..the reason for having 2 entities are- the query result gives back two sets of fields for a job